# How to get author name(whos written the command) into embed title

Tags: javascript, discord, embed, gif

1. Hey so im new at coding and right now i am creating a discord bot for me and my friends.
2. I want a Embed which can show a gif + the author name who has written this.
3. like:
4. (title) @username is tired
5. (gif) --->

Tried this but it didn't work:

```js
case 'sleepy':
    const sleepy = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(${author} is tired)
    .setImage('https://media.giphy.com/media/1forTCExMq1F3M2JjS/giphy.gif')
    .color(0x808080)
    message.channel.send(sleepy);
    break;
```

[Example of outcome (at the very bottom)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWP4n.png)

Comment: Sorry that the code is so caotic

Answer (score 0):

I'm just looking at the embed itself, which is what I'm assuming you're looking to fix.

I'm going to assume `author` is `message.author`, if not, then let me know.

First, is tagging the author. You were close, but you have to use `` to enclose your variables. In addition, instead of using `author`, which would return the @user-id (a string of numbers), I would recommend using `${author.username}` instead since then it would just @ the username of the user.

However, I have not yet found a method where you can tag a user directly in the Title, I have no idea as to why Discord.js doesn't support that. But instead, you can use setDescription as an alternate, simply place `.setDescription(${message.author} is tired)` (with the appropriate backticks since Stack Overflow has markdown that I'm not yet used to).

In addition, you should change `.color` to `.setColor` because that's the naming convention.

So, the new modified code is this:

Title method (cannot directly tag user that I know of)

```
const sleepy = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`@${message.author.username} is tired`)
      .setColor(0x000000)
      message.channel.send(sleepy);
```

Description method (can tag user)

```
const sleepy = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription(`${message.author} is tired`)
      .setColor(0x000000)
      message.channel.send(sleepy);
```

Method without tagging user:

```
const sleepy = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      //Just removed the '@' symbol at the beginning, that's it
      .setTitle(`${message.author.username} is tired`)
      .setColor(0x000000)
      message.channel.send(sleepy);
```

Comment: Hey thank u
now i have a title 
but i wanted that the titel written stil is tight ? how can i change that

Comment: I dont know how to explain it.
but do u know owo bot, when u use a command like owo slap (username)
than the name / sentence is thick without @username 
how can i do this ? :'D

Comment: Could you maybe edit your post to contain an image example of what you mean? I'm confused.

Comment: can i write u on discord or privat ? or can i do it here

Comment: There's an edit option at the bottom section of your post. Could you just put a picture of which embed the owo bot does that you're trying to copy?

Comment: yea u see in the picture bottom. Its written in thick and without @username

Comment: Oh, that's simpler. You just have to remove the `@` symbol in the code and that's it. Btw you tried to edit my answer lol. I've edited my answer accordingly to give you the ideal method at the end

Comment: so now its without the @, thank u!
but how can i get this senctence big and white ? :D
last question :DD

Comment: That's in the title format, so everything's fine, just give it a try and it should work.

Comment: Yeah so it works now ! But now the last thing is that i want it that the print is white and thick

Comment: Are you sure you're using `setTitle` instead of `setDescription`?

Comment: Ah now it works thank u ! i had setDescription

Comment: and how can i do it that before the senctence is my avatar icon ? or of the one who has written the command

Comment: Could you try explaining it in a different way? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: so now i have 
```.setTitle(`${message.author.username} is tired`)``` -> (output) Hamyai is tired!
but before the Hamyai is tired i want that the picture of my profiles shows up u know ?

Comment: This thread is getting a bit long, maybe consider writing a new question for that, but I think the current issue has been resolved now.

Comment: If this answer helped you solve this issue though, please consider clicking the check mark so then people can reference it later on.

Comment: where is the check button

Comment: If you go to the top of my post on the left, then there should be a check shape that you can click on, below the up vote and down vote buttons.